# Java 2.0 Ecosystem compatibility with Cobertura 1.6.1

Tags: sonarqube, cobertura

We are trying to upgrade SonarQube from 3.6.2 to 3.7.4 LTS in order to have PL/SQL plugin working.

As per the plugin Matrix for 3.7.4 LTS version, Java Plugin 2.0 and Cobertura 1.6.1 are recommended.

However, when we restart SonarQube with above plugins, it keeps on reporting below error.

Would appreciate a solution here.

Thanks,

Br,

Error message:

```
2014.06.02 12:32:02 ERROR o.s.s.p.Platform  The plugin 'java' is in version 2.0 whereas the plugin 'cobertura' requires a least a version 2.1.
org.sonar.updatecenter.common.exception.IncompatiblePluginVersionException: The plugin 'java' is in version 2.0 whereas the plugin 'cobertura' requires a least a version 2.1.
    at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferential.addOutgoingDependency(PluginReferential.java:148) ~[sonar-update-center-common-1.8.jar:na]
     at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferentialManifestConverter.fromPluginManifests(PluginReferentialManifestConverter.java:66) ~[sonar-update-center-common-1.8.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.PluginReferentialMetadataConverter.getInstalledPluginReferential(PluginReferentialMetadataConverter.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
     at org.sonar.server.plugins.InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.init(InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.start(InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
     at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
     at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
     at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
     at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-3.7.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Platform.java:251) ~[classes/:na]
     at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:189) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:746) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238) ~[na:na]
     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:689) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:482) ~[na:na]
     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229) ~[na:na]
     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) ~[na:na]
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:281) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
     at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:67) ~[sonar-application-3.7.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:48) ~[sonar-application-3.7.4.jar:na]
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240) ~[wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/02 12:32:02 | 2014-06-02 12:32:02.897:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/opt/sonar_home/war/sonar-server/},file:/opt/sonar_home/war/sonar-server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was in fact an error on the [plugin compatibility matrix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix) which has been fixed now thanks to your feedback.

Please use the version 1.4 of cobertura plugin with version of Java 2.0. You can find it [here](http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-cobertura-plugin/1.4/sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.4.jar).

Comment: benzonico, Tried cobertura 1.5 with Java 2.0 Plugin already. Still the same error.

Comment: [See the full log](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/file/n5025332/Sonar_server_log.txt)

Comment: Edited answer after your update. Thanks a lot for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small update.

Cobertura 1.4 is verified to be working (no more error thrown out during sonar start) with Java 2.0 on Sonar 3.7.4.

You may want to update the compatibility Matrix as well.

Appreciate for the help.